# Plugin eirslett

Tags: spring-boot, yarnpkg

In my spring-boot project, I keep the front-end part in:

> src/main/js

I need to run **yarn build** command.

My pom.xml is:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.github.eirslett</groupId>
    <artifactId>frontend-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
    <configuration>
        <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>
        <workingDirectory>src/main/js</workingDirectory>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>install node and yarn</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>install-node-and-yarn</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>build</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>yarn</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>compile</phase>
            <configuration>
                <yarnInheritsProxyConfigFromMaven>false</yarnInheritsProxyConfigFromMaven>
                <arguments>build</arguments>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Nothing happens. What is wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you're missing the nodeVersion and yarnVersion keys. Example:

```
          <configuration>
              <installDirectory>target</installDirectory>
              <workingDirectory>src/main/js</workingDirectory>
              <nodeVersion>v8.9.3</nodeVersion>
              <yarnVersion>v1.3.2</yarnVersion>
          </configuration>
```

If this doesn't solve the problem, post

- the entire pom.xml
- the command that you execute when you run `mvn`
- the output of the Maven build.